# Google App Script Fill Out Website Form Field

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I have data in my Google Spreadsheet that I would like to use to fill out a website's form.  For example, I have "Title":"Some Company Name" in my Google spreadsheet, and I would like to have a function that opens up a new browser tab, for example, this url (http://www.requestmaker.com/), with the "Request Data:" field already filled out with the "Title" value.

Is this possible with Google Apps Script, or is something else needed?  Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with apps script. Look at chrome extensions.
Apps script could serve you as a backend (proxy) if you dont want to deal with sprewdsheet permission to read it etc. Not something short that can be posted here but doable.